# Keras Lambda Layer for matrix vector multiplication

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to have a lambda layer in keras that performs a vector matrix multiplication, before passing it to another layer. The matrix is fixed (I don't want to learn it). Code below:

```
model.add(Dropout(0.1))    
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x.dot(A)))
model.add(Dense(output_shape, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(<stuff here>)}
```

A is the fixed matrix, and I want to do x.dot(A)

WHen I run this, I get the following error:

`'Tensor' object has no attribute 'dot'`

Same Error when I replace dot with matmul (I am using tensorflow backend)

Finally, when I replace the lambda layer by

`model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x*A))`

I get the error below:

`model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x*G))`

`model.add(Dense(output_shape, activation='softmax'))`

`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_dims'`

I'm new to Keras so any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function for the lambda:

```
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np

numpyA = np.array(define A correctly here, with 2 dimensions)

def multA(x):
    A = K.variable(numpyA)

    return K.dot(x,A)

model.add(Lambda(multA))
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you can add a `Dense` layer with the initial weight being the matrix `A`, and set the arguments `trainable=False` and `use_bias=False`. This layer will be equivalent to a fixed matrix multiplication.

```py
model.add(Dense(A.shape[1], trainable=False, weights=[A], use_bias=False))
```

Comment: THis seems reasonable and I tried it, but get the following: Layer weight shape (1, 265) not compatible with provided weight shape (265, 265) . 265 is A.shape[1] (it's a square matrix)

Comment: Can you provide `model.summary()`? It seems that the layer before has an output dimension equal to 1.

Comment: If the output shape of the previous layer is `(None, 265, 1)`, then I think you can remove the extra axis by adding a `Flatten` layer.

Comment: No the prev layer was (None, 265). I implemented @Daniel's method and that works for me though

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I needed. I need to change the matrix (weight) in each train step and this solution offers a way to do it. Thanks