# Custom Tensorflow layer multiplying vector with scalar

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, customization, keras-layer

I currently have two tensorflow layers, one producing a 1-dimensional output and the other producing a multidimensional output.  How can I build a custom layer multiplying them?

Does this need to be some sort of functional API with multiple inputs and a single output or is there some clearner way?

Answer (score 2):

My first intention was to tell you to use the Functional API and do get the output of both layers and use a `tf.keras.layers.Multiply`, but I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46570963/keras-lambda-layer-for-matrix-vector-multiplication) and I think this can help you solve your problem.

So this answer works well with the Sequential Model.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K


numpyA = np.array(define A correctly here, with 2 dimensions)

def multA(x):
    A = K.variable(numpyA)

    return K.dot(x,A)

model.add(Lambda(multA))
```